# Moving over to red hat ubi-minimal

Tags: docker, redhat, ubi

Bit of a newb question. I'm currently running off Red Hat UBI 8 and am looking to move to Red Hat 8 UBI-Minimal.

My current docker file has something like this in it:

```
RUN groupadd -r -g 1000 myuser \
  && useradd -r -u 1000 -g myuser -m -d /opt/myuser -s /bin/bash myuser
RUN mkdir /deployments \
  && chmod 755 /deployments \
  && chown -R myuser /deployments
```

I was looking into this more and at first i thought ubi-minimal might be a "rootless" container but a simple test i ran on my local shows otherwise:

docker run -p 8080:8080 -it myreg/redhat/ubi8/ubi-minimal

[image]

That means I should be looking to replicate the above lines against ubi-minimal but it seems like groupadd & useradd don't exist in that image. How can i replicate docker file lines the above for the ubi-minimal image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the `groupadd` and `useradd` commands by installing the `shadow-utils` package like this

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-minimal
RUN microdnf install shadow-utils
RUN groupadd -r -g 1000 myuser \
  && useradd -r -u 1000 -g myuser -m -d /opt/myuser -s /bin/bash myuser
RUN mkdir /deployments \
  && chmod 755 /deployments \
  && chown -R myuser /deployments
```